# Inter-causal reasoning: How to solve probability with two conditions?

Tags: probability

Below is the scheme of conditional dependence and the probabilities of events:

[image]

```
P(A=1) = 0.01
P(A=0) = 0.99
P(B=1) = 0.1
P(B=0) = 0.9
P(C=1|A=0,B=0) = 0.1
P(C=1|A=0,B=1) = 0.5
P(C=1|A=1,B=0) = 0.6
P(C=1|A=1,B=1) = 0.9
```

Given the probabilities above I wanted to calculate P(B=1|C=1) and P(B=1|C=1,A=1) but didn't get the correct result.

I wrote the probabilistic function the following way:

```
P(A, B, C) = P(A)P(B)P(C|A, B)
```

and then set the variables

```
P(B=1, C=1) = P(A=0, B=1, C=1) + P(A=1, B=1, C=1)=
=P(A=0)P(B=1)P(C=1|A=0, B=1) + P(A=1)P(B=1)P(C=1|A=1, B=1)=
=0.99*0.1*0.5 + 0.01*0.1*0.9 = 0.0495
```

The result however is not correct and don't know where is the error. I would be very thankful if anyone could correct/explain what's wrong.

Comment: You said you were asked `P(B=1|C=1)` but you computed `P(B=1,C=1)` hence you are off by the factor `P(C=1)` (which you will need to compute).

Comment: Is P(C=1) = ( P(C=1|A=0,B=0)+P(C=1|A=0,B=1)+P(C=1|A=1,B=0)+P(C=1|A=1,B=1) )/4 ?

Comment: Maybe because 0.99*0.1*0.5 + 0.01*0.1*0.9 = 0.0504 (and not 0.0495) ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884728/how-to-solve-probability-with-two-conditions-with-explanation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typical way I do inter-causal reasoning is to flip the conditional probabilities around --

$$
\begin{align}
P(B = 1 \vert C = 1) & = \frac{P(B = 1, C = 1)}{P(C = 1)} \\
& = \frac{P(C = 1 \vert B = 1)P(B = 1)}{P(C = 1)} \\ \\
P(B = 1 \vert C = 1, A = 1) & = \frac{P(B = 1, C = 1, A = 1)}{P(C = 1, A = 1)} \\
& = \frac{P(C = 1 \vert B = 1, A = 1)P(B = 1)P(A = 1)}{P(C = 1, A = 1)} \\
& = \frac{P(C = 1 \vert B = 1, A = 1) P(B = 1) P(A = 1)}{P(C = 1 \vert A = 1)P(A = 1)} \\
& = \frac{P(C = 1 \vert B = 1, A = 1) P(B = 1)}{P(C = 1 \vert A = 1)}
\end{align}
$$

Does that help?

Comment: And how do you calculate P(C=1) ?
Is it `( P(C=1|A=0,B=0) + P(C=1|A=0,B=1) ) * ( P(C=1|A=1,B=0) + P(C=1|A=1,B=1) )` ?

Comment: No. That would give you P(C) > 1

Comment: This is very old, but how is it that $P(B = 1, C = 1, A = 1) = P(C = 1 \vert B = 1, A = 1)P(B = 1)P(A = 1)$ in the second half? More specifically, why are we assuming that $A$ and $B$ are independent, when it's the case that variable $C$ is observed? As far as I know, in a $v$-structure, the middle variable being observed now means that the two parents are dependent.