# How to solve probability with two conditions (with explanation)?

Tags: probability, graph-theory, bayes-theorem

This is an extension over this question:
[Inter-causal reasoning: How to solve probability with two conditions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126216/inter-causal-reasoning-how-to-solve-probability-with-two-conditions)

I'm a beginner in probability, and trying to deeply understand what is happening underneath.

To sum up what the question is about:

We've got a graph of (binary) events:

$$
A \rightarrow C \leftarrow B
$$

We're given probabilities of:
$$
P(A), P(\bar A), P(B), P(\bar B)
\\
P(C|A, B)\\
P(C|A, \bar B)\\
P(C|\bar A, B)\\
P(C|\bar A, \bar B)
$$
Where $P(A)$ is a probability of occurrence of event $A$ and $P(\bar A)$ is a probability of event $A$ not occurring.

---

We have to find probability of: $P(B|C)$ and $P(B|C,A)$.

Before going further I'd like to say, that I'd like to find out a bit more things and, of course, be aware of theorems used.

I'll begin with really simple ones (numbering done to ease answering the questions):

1. Does $P(B|C,A)$ means: *Probability that event $B$ will occur given event $A$ and event $C$ occurred* ?
2. Are the events $A$ and $B$ independent? I see a *V-structure* in here, so we've got no *active trail* in here, right? So they're independent.
3. We can write (*Bayes theorem*) that $P(B|C) = \frac{P(C|B)P(B)}{P(C)}$.

   3.1. To get $P(C|B)$ can we do conditioning and reduction on $B$ ?

   3.1.1. If yes, then does it equals to (why, what is the rule; my intuition says "B"): 
   $$
   Option~A\\
   P(C|B) = P(C|B,A)+P(C|B,\bar A)\\
   \\
   Option~B\\
   P(C|B) = P(C|B,A)P(A)+P(C|B,\bar A)P(\bar A)
   $$

   3.1.2. Does the (in)dependence of $A$ and $B$ affects somehow the way we can count $P(C|B)$ ?

   3.2. How can we count $P(C)$? Is it:
   $$
   P(C) = ( P(C|A,B)+ P(C|A, \bar B) ) * ( P(C| \bar A,B) + P(C|\bar A, \bar B) )
   $$
4. Counting $P(B|C,A)$:

   4.1. **I have counted it**, but I cannot recall how, and I don't have my notes in here. It only means, that I didn't understood it, as I cannot do it again ;) I thought I can use a *Bayes theorem* in here, but will this turn out to be $\frac{P(C,A|B)P(C,A)}{P(B)}$ ? It doesn't look well.. And, can I use somehow the fact of (in)dependence of $A$ and $B$ in here?

   4.2. I know there's an answer in the connected question, but it's not about getting the answer. I want to understand how to figure out this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes, due to the collider at $C$. It seems like you're already familiar with $d$-separation.
3. Your statement about Bayes's Theorem is correct. I do not understand what you mean in 3.1. Option A is incorrect, and Option B is correct. Option B comes from
   $$P(C \mid B) = P(C \cap A \mid B) + P(C \cap \overline{A} \mid B),$$
   which is due to [marginalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution#Two-variable_case). As for 3.1.2., I don't think you can exploit anything more about the independence of $A$ and $B$ when computing $P(C\mid B)$, but it shows up when calculating $P(C)$ (which again is by marginalization):
   \begin{align*}P(C)&=P(C \cap A \cap B) + P(C \cap \overline{A} \cap B) + P(C \cap A \cap \overline{B}) + P(C \cap \overline{A} \cap \overline{B})\\
   &=P(C\mid A,B)P(A)P(B) + P(C\mid \overline{A},B)P(\overline{A})P(B) + P(C\mid A,\overline{B})P(A)P(\overline{B}) + P(C\mid \overline{A},\overline{B})P(\overline{A})P(\overline{B})\end{align*}
   The independence shows up in an intermediate step that I omitted: $P(A \mid B)P(B) = P(A)P(B)$.
4. $\quad$
   \begin{align*}
   P(B \mid A,C) &= \frac{P(C \mid A,B)\cdot P(B \mid A)}{P(C \mid A)} & \text{Bayes's Theorem}\\
   &= \frac{P(C \mid A,B)P(B)}{P(C \mid A)} & \text{independence of $A$ and $B$}
   \end{align*}
   You can compute $P(C \mid A)$ in the same way as in #3 above.